# JPA sequence generator giving Null value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA over hibernate in my application . I have sequence generator in one of my domain objects as given below:-

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CPAY_PE_FORMAT_HTML_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="CPAY_PE_FORMAT_HTML_SEQ",sequenceName="CPAY_PE_FORMAT_HTML_SEQ")
```

But it is giving me null value inspite if i fire below query in my database .

```
select CPAY_PE_FORMAT_HTML_SEQ.nextval from dual;
```

it gives me correct value. Please help.

Comment: Can you supply configuration information? Enough information we need to recreate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar problem.To fix this i have to add **allocationSize** to sequence generator.

@SequenceGenerator(name="IMPORT_RUN_ID_GEN",sequenceName="SEQ_IMPORT_RUN_ID"
,**allocationSize=1**)

By default alllocation size is 50. Either you MUST declare INCREMENT BY 50 on the DB side or whatever increment value is in DB provide the same value as allocationsize in sequenceGeenerator or **allocationSize=1** will work in both case because hibernate will fire query in DB every time new ID is required.

Please try to add **allocationsize=1** in your sequenceGenerator too and run after that.